# Overlay of two dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Problem:

I have two dataframes viz '**infm**' and '**ufl**'. In 'ufl', *Age* and *Salary* column for Ben and Creg is updated. I want to update the corresponding row in 'infm' too .

Approach Taken:

I am iterating through each row of 'infm' and taking 'Name' column to match both dataframe. If corresponding names are matched, then updating the Age column of 'infm' with value in 'ufl'

```
Input:

NAME    AGE    SALARY   COUNTRY
Adam    24     25000     x
Ben     25     30000     y
Creg    23     22000     x
Dawood  25     30000     w
```

```
Update on two rows of Input:

NAME    AGE    SAlARY    COUNTRY
Ben     36     90000      y
Creg    34     92000      x
```

```
Expected Output:
NAME    AGE    SALARY   COUNTRY
Adam    24     25000     x
Ben     36     90000     y
Creg    34     92000     x
Dawood  25     30000     w
```

```
Actual output:
NAME    AGE    SALARY   COUNTRY
Adam    24     25000     x
Ben     25     30000     y
Creg    23     22000     x
Dawood  25     30000     w
```

```
Code used:

import pandas as pd
infm=pd.read_excel('D:/data/test.xls')
ufl=pd.read_excel('D:/data/test1.xls')

for row in infm.iterrows():
    a=row[1]['Name']
    b=ufl['Name'].unique().tolist()
    for i in b:
        if i==a:
            row[1]['Age']=(ufl['Age'][ufl['Name']==a]).tolist()[0]
```

Comment: Please dont put images of data into questions https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question has a long discussion on it, but basically we cannot read what you are doing...

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrennan I have removed images.